# How to change UIImageView Image with the same name

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, xcode4.3

I create a Image with the code:

```
UIImageView *Event01 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Event01.jpg"]];
Event01.frame = CGRectMake(4, 48, 75, 75);
Event01.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
Event01.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.view addSubview:Event01];
```

But I decide to change the image and I erase the Image and upload other with the same name, but when I build it there is the old photo. So what I should do to update the UIImage?

Because I had work with MainStoryboard and there I erase the name of the Image, then I upload the new one and just then I put the name to the imageview.

Thanks for the help,

Comment: What do you mean by "upload"?

Comment: Upload to the xcode project..

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it should still work; you might've deleted the new image by accident?
First rename the new image to Event02 and then change the code to reflect that; maybe then it will work? 
I think it is more of a personal error than a coding problem. Make sure when you delete the image move it to trash, and when uploading the image make sure to add it to the build target.